# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError with HttpResponseCache and DiskLruCache

Tags: java, android, noclassdeffounderror, httpresponsecache

I´m trying test this cache Library in a new project Android.
When I run the project, I get this Logcat:

```
01-24 03:45:31.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1983): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-24 03:45:31.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1983): Process: com.test_cache, PID: 1983
01-24 03:45:31.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1983): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.jakewharton.DiskLruCache
01-24 03:45:31.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at com.integralblue.httpresponsecache.compat.libcore.net.http.HttpResponseCache.<init>(HttpResponseCache.java:83)
01-24 03:45:31.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at com.integralblue.httpresponsecache.HttpResponseCache.<init>(HttpResponseCache.java:155)
01-24 03:45:31.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at com.integralblue.httpresponsecache.HttpResponseCache.install(HttpResponseCache.java:192)
01-24 03:45:31.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at com.test_cache.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
01-24 03:45:31.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
01-24 03:45:31.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-24 03:45:31.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
01-24 03:45:31.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
01-24 03:45:31.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-24 03:45:31.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
01-24 03:45:31.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-24 03:45:31.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-24 03:45:31.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
01-24 03:45:31.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-24 03:45:31.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-24 03:45:31.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
01-24 03:45:31.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
01-24 03:45:31.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I copied both jars from projects [HttpResponseCache by Craig Andrews](https://github.com/candrews/HttpResponseCache) and [DiskLruCache by Jake Wharton](https://github.com/JakeWharton/DiskLruCache) in my libs folder:
[image: Project Files]

This is my MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final long httpCacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MiB
    final File httpCacheDir = new File(getCacheDir(), "http");

    try {
        com.integralblue.httpresponsecache.HttpResponseCache.install(httpCacheDir, httpCacheSize);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }        
}
```

I read in other threads that it´s problem of the order, so in the Order & Export tab in the Java Build Path, I put this in first place:
[image: Build Path]
[image: Order and Export]

I clean the proyect, rebuild and nothing work, the problem persist...
Any idea...??

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you used **disklrucache-2.0.2.jar** and **httpresponsecache-1.3.jar**

In library **httpresponsecache-1.3.jar** use **disklrucache-1.2.1.jar**

In **disklrucache-1.2.1.jar** the package is: **com.jakewharton** but in version 2.0.2 the package is changed to **com.jakewharton.disklrucache**

That is the root cause.

If you wanna use **disklrucache** you should use version 1.2.1

You can download from here: http://www.mediafire.com/download/e2q4vz7kdlwxxr3/disklrucache-1.2.1.jar (.jar)

or source file: https://www.mediafire.com/?933nqqe9j4227cc (.jar)

Hope this can help you.

[image]

Comment: BRI-LLI-ANT!! It was driving me crazy. Thank you very very much!

Comment: Welcome. Please to be careful when using java lib. :)